# How to get the common values in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

For example i am having an array of data as below

```
var arrData = ["40-25",null,null,"40-25","50-48",null,"30-25","40-23","50-48","30-25",null,"50-48","40-45","40-45","40-45","40-50","40-50",null,null,null,null,null,"50-48"]
```

i need to list the same data as below in javascript

```
var arrDataSorted = ["40-25","50-48","30-25","40-23","40-45","40-50","40-50"]
```

need only the common data that replicates also the null to be removed.

What is the best solution to solve this.

Comment: Can you please define the `best`? Less code or less runtime or anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove *null* values and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get the unique values. Finally use the [`Spread syntax (...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to transform the set result into an array.

Try the following way:

```js
var arrData = ["40-25",null,null,"40-25","50-48",null,"30-25","40-23","50-48","30-25",null,"50-48","40-45","40-45","40-45","40-50","40-50",null,null,null,null,null,"50-48"];

var arrDataSorted = [...new Set(arrData.filter(i => i))];
console.log(arrDataSorted);
```

Comment: I think better use `map` instead of `filter`. Filter is used  to pass a specific test not just create a new array

Comment: @csandreas1, as I could not find that easy, I think you can add your answer....

Comment: just to add a small explanation here. `new Set()` makes an array of only unique values and the filter method is filtering out only truthy elements in the array, `null` is falsy.                                                                            
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set                                                        https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

You can create a set from an array which will automatically remove duplicates:

```
let arrData = ["40-25",null,null,"40-25","50-48",null,"30-25","40-23","50-48","30-25",null,"50-48","40-45","40-45","40-45","40-50","40-50",null,null,null,null,null,"50-48"];

let set = new Set(arrData);
```

This will still keep the null, which you can remove with a `delete` call, and convert back to array with the spread `...` operator. The final code will be:

```
let set = new Set(arrData);
set.delete(null);
let distinctArr = [...set];
```

Answer (score 0):

add the values into the set if the value is not `null` and convert it to array.

```js
var arrData = ["40-25",null,null,"40-25","50-48",null,"30-25","40-23","50-48","30-25",null,"50-48","40-45","40-45","40-45","40-50","40-50",null,null,null,null,null,"50-48"];

var setData = new Set();
for(var data of arrData) {
    if(data) {
        setData.add(data);
    }
}

var arrDataSorted = [...setData];
console.log(arrDataSorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your code:

```
function removeCommonValues(arr) {
  let result = [];
  for(let i=0; i < arr.length-1; ++i) {
    if(result.includes(arr[i]) === false && arr[i] !== null)
      result.push(arr[i])
  }
  return result
}
```

Usage:

```
removeCommonValues(["40-25",null,null,"40-25","50-48",null,"30-25","40-23","50-48","30-25",null,"50-48","40-45","40-45","40-45","40-50","40-50",null,null,null,null,null,"50-48"]) // Return ["40-25", "50-48", "30-25", "40-23", "40-45", "40-50"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrData = ["40-25",null,null,"40-25","50-48",null,"30-25","40-23","50-48","30-25",null,"50-48","40-45","40-45","40-45","40-50","40-50",null,null,null,null,null,"50-48"]
var set = new Set();
      for ( var i = 0 ; i< arrData.length;i++ ) {
           if(arrData[i]!==null) {
                set.add(arrData[i]);
           }
      }
var newArr = [...set]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array built-in reducer method](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce), in the next code i'm starting with an empty array, and i'm only returning the items that are not null and are not already in the array.

```
const data = arrData.reduce((state, value) => {
   if(value && !state.includes(value)) {
        return [...state, value];
   }

   return state;
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

The function can be in a separated file to be reused between multiple pages. Then you can call that function to filter distinct values that are not null.

```js
var arrData = ["40-25",null,null,"40-25","50-48",null,"30-25","40-23","50-48","30-25",null,"50-48","40-45","40-45","40-45","40-50","40-50",null,null,null,null,null,"50-48"];

function fn(value,index,self){
return self.indexOf(value) === index && value;
 }

console.log(arrData.filter(fn));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrData = ["40-25",null,null,"40-25","50-48",null,"30-25","40-23","50-48","30-25",null,"50-48","40-45","40-45","40-45","40-50","40-50",null,null,null,null,null,"50-48"]

const output = [];
arrData.forEach(val => {
  if(output.indexOf(val) === -1 && val !== null) {
    output.push(val);
  }
});

console.log(output);
```